# UIView takes too long to update

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, ios-simulator

In an iPad app, I have a bunch of UIImageViews inside a bigger UIView. Each UIImageView contains a thumbnail that is generated in a separate thread (so as not to freeze the application). After thumbnail has been successfully generated I call `setNeedsDisplay` on main thread, however, it doesn't update the UIImageViews as the thumbs become available (I can see them in the log), rather it takes about 5 seconds and then displays all of them at once.

here's what I am doing when a thumbnail has been created in a separate thread:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your main thread up to?  If your application waits until all the thumbnails are available before redrawing, then it sounds like maybe you are inadvertently blocking on your main thread until your thumbnailing queue has emptied.  How are you setting up the threads?

Comment: no,my main thread lets the user interact with the views (drag them, arrange them, etc). So it doesn't stall. That is the reason I am using a separate thread to load thumbnails so that UI doesn't look jerky. I am using NSOperationQueue for threading and my logs show that threads roughly take about 200 ms to finish their job. but the thumbnails only appear after about 5 seconds.

Comment: I know you said that you are calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your main thread, but are you interacting with UIKit *at all* from a background thread?

Comment: no, not at all. I am just reading the source images, resizing them and setting them on UIIImageView, oh wait, I can't set them on UIImageView can I?    oops. it was a silly mistake. am embarrassed. thanks Jim. problem fixed.

Comment: No worries.  I only thought of this because I made the exact same mistake last week (writing a threaded thumbnailer, funnily enough).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't tell cocoa that it have to redraw "now". 
With `setNeedsDisplay` you can onely order a redraw, because drawing is ra rather expensive procces.

> **[setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC)**
>
> You can use this method or the
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect:  to notify the
>   system that your view’s contents need
>   to be redrawn. This method makes a
>   note of the request and returns
>   immediately. The view is not actually
>   redrawn until the next drawing cycle,
>   at which point all invalidated views
>   are updated.

Mybe its a better and  more performant solution to wait for all generated thumbnials?!

Comment: when I drag the UIImageViews, shouldn't they be redrawn. what I can't understand is why it takes a long time before they start showing thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSNotification. Send a notification from your thread loading the images when an image is ready. Your view controller can observe these notifications and update the view as they arrive.